# Moq: CallBase on an explicitly implemented interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have some code similar to the following:

```
    public interface IBase
    {
        public bool DoTest();
    }

    public interface ISpecific : IBase
    {
        public bool DoSpecifictTest();
        
        bool IBase.DoTest()
        {
            return this.DoSpecifictTest();
        }
    }
```

Now I want to write a test using Moq that verifies the implementation of the explicitly implemented function in ISpecific to call the `DoSpecificTest()`

So I have a testcase similar to:

```
    public class TestISpecific 
    {
        [Fact]
        public static void TestDoTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            Mock<ISpecific> mock = new() { CallBase = true };

            //Act
            mock.Object.DoTest();

            //Assert
            mock.Verify(x => x.DoSpecifictTest(), Times.Once);
        }
    }
```

But this does not call the implemented `DoTest()` function. Sow how do instruct the `Mock<ISpecific> mock` to call the implemented function and/or how to invoke the correct function on `mock.Object`? As the current test function fails as it does not call the correct function.

Comment: ISpecific has an implemented function. And this function I want to test. So I have to instruct the Mock to call this function (which I try here with 'CallBase = true')

Comment: That question is asked [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/972#issuecomment-761722499)

Comment: There is a difference. This function is an explicit implementation of `IBase.DoTest()` not a function of `ISpecific`

Comment: which means you may still need to do a cast. something like `mock.As<IBase>().Setup(_ => _.DoTest()).CallBase();`. But at this point, I am not sure if that will work the way you want it to.

Comment: In similar case I used `.As<T>` for a specific interface. Like `mock.As<IBase>.Verify(...)`